# How can the linux CFS scheduler prevent a task with a very small vruntime from starving the processor?

Tags: linux, runtime, scheduler

So after a task eats up its time slice, it would be re-inserted into the red-black tree. If the task has slept for a long time previously , leading to a very small vruntime compared to other tasks in the runqueue, then it will be repetitively re-inserted as the left-most node in the red-black tree, right?  Consequently it will always be picked up as the next task to run? I have checked the source code in core.c and fair.c, I didn't see any place where this task should yield to other tasks. Though in the funciton pick_next_entity(), I do see some tasks such cfs_rq->next,cfs_rq->last or etc.. which might have higher running priority,I do not think this is the correct place to prevent a task with very small vruntime from taking a processor for a too long time,right? Does anyone have a clue? Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer.
When  task is dequeue from the runqueue, this will be called：
se->vruntime -= cfs_rq->min_vruntime
When task is again enqueued to the runqueue, this will be called:
se->vruntime += cfs_rq->min_vruntime
So actually only the offset of the vruntime will be stored when the task is sleeping and the offset will be added again when it wakes up.

Comment: I understood your point in case process wakes up after sleep. But can you explain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947547/linux-cfs-scheduler this question. in this how cfs prevents starvation if there are two processes p1 and p2 ,p1 is executing from quite a long time so its vruntime would be large now if process p2 starts its vruntime would be zero then the new task would be scheduled against p1 because its vruntime is less.

Comment: @anshulgarg I think `vruntime` is inherited by a child from a parent upon creation so `vruntime` doesn't start at zero.

Comment: Hi @Hao, could you please be a bit more explicit? Is `min_vruntime` the static value (usually defaulted to 1-2ms), of the minimum timeslice given to a given task (as to avoid context switching too much)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be "fairer" if sleeping tasks got at least some boost? Wouldn't it make more sense to reinsert at exactly `min_vruntime` (i.e., as the leftmost node but not behind other runnable tasks) as long as the task slept long enough?